# Youtube-api квоты на загрузку видео

Tags: youtube-api

Зарегистрировался в консоли google, создал свой проект и включил youtube api v3.
Делаю загрузку видео с сервера, у меня сделана через Oauth2(с моего аккаунта) т.е. я первый раз подтвердил, получил refresh токен и теперь просто обновляю access токен для загрузки видео.
Проблема в квотах: я читал что youtube предоставляет квоту в 1000000(один миллион) единиц в сутки, на загрузку видео тратиться +-1600, но у меня почему-то лимит 3000000(три миллиона), НО в тот же момент написано 10000 в день.
А десять тысяч - это 6 видео всего.
Не могли бы вы мне разъяснить какие все таки квоты и почему у меня в день только 10000?
На первом скриншоте мы видим, что потрачено только 11184 единицы из 3 000 000
а на втором что потрачен практически весь лимит(почти 10 000)

[image: список всех квот]

[image: ежедневная квота]

Comment: я вообще не понимаю в чем смысл ютуб апи если из за этих квот любое приложение упадет за 5 минут, кто нить вообще в курса как это работает и в чем смысл этого ???

Answer (score 0):

Такие же квоты у всех по умолчанию. То что написано 300к - речь о лимите за промежуток в 100 секунд. Вообще то что они написали про 300к за 100сек при 10к в день - выглядит как насмешка. Есть возможность отправить запрос на увеличение лимита. Но не известно на сколько они его повысят.